# Removing duplicates with PowerShell based on the first n characters

Tags: powershell

I have a CSV file that reads as follows:

```
TYPE     VALUE
Quote    This is the first quote
Quote    This is the first quote!
Quote    This is the first quote?
Quote    Short quote
Quote    Short quote!
Quote    This a significantly longer third quote
Quote    This a significantly longer third quote.
```

I am trying to figure out how to identify the first unique instance of the quote and remove the repeats. Extraneous characters at the end of the repeating strings are known, but the length of the string may vary from a couple of characters to over 40.

Comment: can you describe the expected difference between the desired value and the extras?

Comment: inside of a loop If NextLine.StartsWith(PreviousLine).  Write some code and tell us what's not working for you.

Comment: Define "unique". Technically all of the values in your sample are unique.

Comment: By "unique" I mean the string without punctuation marks as the last character.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to ignore trailing punctuation for determining the unique values you could group the records by a custom property and then process the groups like this:

```
Import-Csv 'C:\path\to\input.csv' |
    Group-Object { $_.VALUE -replace '[\.!\?]+$' } |
    ForEach-Object {
        $_.Group |
            Sort-Object Length -Descending |
            Select-Object -Last 1
    }
```

Alternatively, replace the original `VALUE` property with a calculated property and select the unique records:

```
Import-Csv 'C:\path\to\input.csv' |
    Select-Object TYPE, @{n='VALUE';e={$_.VALUE -replace '[\.!\?]+$'} -Unique
```

To remove any punctuation from the end of each value you can also use the escape sequence `\p{P}` instead of the character class `[\.!\?]`, as Theo mentioned in the comments.

Comment: You can also use `\p{P}` shorthand to remove trailing punctuation marks: `$_.VALUE -replace '\p{P}+$', ''`